# Sum a number with others in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm given a array of numbers, `[5,1,3, etc, etc]`.

I want to sum `5+1` and save the results in new array called `results`, then sum `5+3` and save results, and then sum `5+etc` till I reach the last number.

After that I want to sum `1+3` and save results.

Then sum `1+etc` till the last.

Then sum `3+etc` till I reach the last and so on...

But I don't want to sum a number with itself.

The order of the numbers in the `results` array doesn't matter, what matters is that the expected numbers exist in the returned array.

I want to achieve this without using nested loops in order to maintain linear time complexity.

Examples:

- For the input `[5,1,3`], I expect `[6, 8, 4]` (in any order) because `5+1=6`, `5+3=8`, and `1+3=4`.
- For the input `[5,1,3,2]` I expect `[6, 8, 7, 4, 3, 5]` (in any order) because `5+1=6`, `5+3=8`, `5+2=7`, `1+3=4`, `1+2=3`, and `3+2=5`.

I've tried this:

```
function sumTwo(arr) {
  
  const results = []

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    let sum = arr[i] + arr[i + 1]
    results.push(sum)
  }
  console.log(results)
}

console.log(sumTwo([5, 1, 3]));
```

...but it gives me the wrong output (`[6,4]` instead of `[6,8,4]`).

Comment: @Kamo as noted on the answer below, there is no linear solution for this since there will always be a quadratic number of sums to be completed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can now see that to achieve this in linear may not be possible

Answer (score 5):

You can optimize the code a bit to make it more efficient within the O(n^2) boundary. One possible approach is using the concept of a sliding window. But again, it won't reduce the time complexity to O(n).

```
function sumTwo(arr) {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      results.push(arr[i] + arr[j]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

const output = sumTwo([5, 1, 3]);
console.log(output); // outputs: [6, 8, 4]
```

This won't help you escape the O(n^2) time complexity. I'm not sure that you can achieve the desired result without using a nested loop.

Comment: I'm aware of this approach its quadratic though I need a method if there is any to achieve this is linear.

Comment: @Kamo There are a quadratic number of sums to be completed so any solution will be O(n^2)

Answer (score -5):

you can create second results when you create results for first element.

when you create second result for first element you can ignore first element this is first result for second element and etc...

you know?

Comment: in doing so, every element summation will have its own array?

Comment: yes, and this is correct answer. I don't know what -1 is it!